# When Scrolled RecyclerView, my view is not displaying quickly as expected but with some delay

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, textview

I have a  Coordinator layout which has TextView inside it, when I opened the fragment I have a text to display and upon scrolling up, it should get disappeared. Again, once we scroll down, the text has to display again.

```
mProductListView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                switch (newState) {
                    case 1: nextAvailable.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.height = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 170);
                        appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                        toolbarLayoutParams.bottomMargin = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 44);
                        toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);

                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleMarginBottom((int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 44));
                    break;

                    case 0:
                        nextAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        layoutParams = appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.height = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 170 + 32);
                        appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                        toolbarLayoutParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                        toolbarLayoutParams.bottomMargin = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 44 + 32);
                        toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);

                        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleMarginBottom((int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 44 + 32));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

I can see the text getting disappeared and upon scrolled down again, after a delay of 2-3sec, I can see the text displaying. How can i overcome this delay and have a smooth UI upon Scrolled Up/Down?